# forgotten credentials (superuser and password) in Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django

Forgotten superuser name and password in Django project. What is the correct way to recover it specially the superuser name? Is it a good practice to create a new superuser to get to admin panel and recover the forgotten superuser name from there or there is another way to recover it in terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python manage.py changepassword <username>
```

Comment: upvoted because it can be used in combination with a lookup in the django database for superuser name: 
```
select username
from auth_user
where is_superuser = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the usernames (but not the password since it is hashed) of super users by making a query in the shell (`python manage.py shell`), while doing this you can also change their password to something new if you want by using the `set_password` method:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


UserModel = get_user_model()
superusers = UserModel.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
for user in superusers:
    print(user.username)
    # Want to reset their password? Run below line
    user.set_password('new_password')
```

You can of course create a new superuser using `python manage.py createsuperuser` if you want to.